# Switch Parent Page and Child Page

Tags: structure, parent, child

Is there a way to switch the parent page with one of the child pages? I would like to avoid creating a new page for each child page under the new parent page.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you carefully reviewed the documentation? Have you tried any test re-orders on a dev server? Have you considered writing your own solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I follow, but can you just drag one to go underneath another parent and then move the parent under it?